# Upload word document or pdf to mysql database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, pdf, doc

Is it possible to upload .docx, .pdf files to mysql database using c#?
I searched a lot but all i found was ways to upload image files,
If there is a way that could help please let me know thanks
P.S the application is desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. That answers your question.

Now search again! Using [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Upload+word+document+or+pdf+to+mysql+database+using+c%23&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=upload+word+document+or+pdf+to+mysql+database+using+c%23&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=571e42b11f7a423b92d0380180b453c1) (or whatever you want) returns heaps of results. The first search result links to [this page](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10074732/upload-a-word-or-pdf-file.aspx) which provides sample code.